Why the vector space defined as the set of all real functions with domain in the natural numbers equals $\mathbb R^\infty$?
My linear algebra textbook showcases this example of a vector space:

The set of all real functions $f,g: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$, where the following operations are defined:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(f+g)(x) &= f(x) + g(x) \\
(af)(x) &= a\cdot f(x), \qquad a \in\mathbb{R} 
\end{aligned}
$$

Then on next page it says this vector space is $\mathbb{R}^\infty$. Why?

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $f=(f(1),f(2),f(3),...,f(n),...)\in \mathbb R^\infty$

That's a choice of notation. I would have written $\mathbf{R}^\mathbf{N}$.

Check that is satisfies the definition of a vector space.

To a topologist, $\mathbb R^\infty$ is actually something different, namely the set of all real functions $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ satisfying an extra restriction: $\exists M \in \mathbb N , \forall m \ge M, f(m)=0$.

There is a correspondence between elements $f$ of the vector space and sequences $(f(1), f(2), f(3), …, f(n), …),$ which are elements of $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\times\cdots\mathbb R\cdots=\mathbb R^\infty$, since each $f(x)\in\mathbb R$.

A more appropriate notation might be $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, since $A^B$ usually denotes the collection of all functions $B \to A$.
However, do bear in mind that elements of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ are hence functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, and there is another way of framing that set: real-valued sequences! (A sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots$ which takes values in $S$ is formally a function $\mathbb{N} \to S$ where $a(n) \mapsto a_n$.)
Sequences are sometimes thought of as vectors of infinite length. That is, where an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n \in \mathbb{N}$) may be written as $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$, we may think of extending this to an infinitely long sequence $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots)$. In this framing, $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ becomes a little more natural: if $\mathbb{R}^n$ represents sequences or vectors of length $n$, $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ represents those of infinite length.
Then your operations on sequences become just as natural as those on vectors: letting $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty := (x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots)$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty + (y_i)_{i=1}^\infty &:= (x_i + y_i)_{i=1}^\infty \\
\alpha \cdot (x_i)_{i=1}^\infty &:= (\alpha \cdot x_i)_{i=1}^\infty \\
(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty, (y_i)_{i=1}^\infty &\in \mathbb{R}^\infty \\
\alpha &\in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}$$
and you can verify the usual axioms of a vector space very easily.

The power notation for sets originates in an abbreviation for the Cartesian product of a set with itself:
$$A\times A=\{(a,b)|a,b\in A\}\equiv A^2,$$
i.e., the product of a set with itself is written as a square as if it were a number (as a matter of fact, the number of elements of the Cartesian product is the product of the cardinalities of the two sets separately).
From there it follows naturally to write $A^3,A^4,\ldots,A^n,\ldots$ for the set of all tuples of length $3,4,\ldots$ etc. whose elements are taken from $A.$
But $A^n$ can also be described as the set of all mappings from the finite set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to $A:$ the mapping $f$ that sends the numbers $1,\ldots,n$ to the elements $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ can be identified with the tuple $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in A^n$ and the correspondence is one-to-one and onto.
From there it is only a small step to consider the set of all mappings from any set $B,$ not necessarily finite, to $A$ and call it a "product" where the elements of the (possibly infinite) tuples are indexed by the elements of $B.$ This set of all mappings $B\to A$ is also written with a power notation:
$$A^B\equiv\{f:B\to A\}$$
If $A$ has an algebraic structure, such as a vector space, then very often $A^B$ can naturally be equipped with a similar structure: just apply the algebraic operations (in this case, addition and real scalar multiplication) on each component of the tuples separately.
The notation $\mathbb R^\infty$ is ambiguous because it does not specify which (presumably infinite) set is used to index the tuples of real numbers. As one commenter suggested, $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ indicates more explicitly that the maps originate in the natural numbers, or equivalently, that the elements of the infinite tuples are indexed by natural numbers.
